# Modify type of dictionary items

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in the following format.

```
{"id": 1, "name": "user", "salary": Decimal(1000)}
```

I would like to convert all the items in the dictionary which has a type Decimal to float. What is the pythonic way of doing it?

The key names are not fixed.

In other words, how can I rewrite the following code in a pythonic way?

```
for key, value in record.items():
    if isinstance(value, Decimal):
        record[key] = float(value)
```

Comment: You pretty much got it!

Comment: I don't see how this code isn't pythonic. You could've used a dictionary comprehension, but it'd create a whole new dictionary, it won't modify the original. So, your code is fine, to my mind.

Comment: The code you have looks very Pythonic to me as it is. If you are refering to `dict-comprehensions`, you could do `{k: (float(v) if isinstance(v, Decimal) else v) for k, v in record.items()}`

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop is perfectly Pythonic as it is. If you are OK with creating a new dictionary instead of modifying the existing one, you could either use a `for` loop:

```
new_record = {}
for k, v in record.items():
    new_record[k] = float(v) if isinstance(v, Decimal) else v
```

or shorten it to a dict comprehension:

```
record = {k: float(v) if isinstance(v, Decimal) else v for k, v in record.items()}
```

Creating a new dictionary this way has the advantage that it allows you to filter out keys and add new keys in the same loop, should you ever need to.

Comment: Modifying a dictionary in-place is *fine* here since no keys are being added or removed (no dictionary re-sizing is occuring)

Comment: @jpp. Probably just my paranoia. I'll check momentarily

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. You're right. I have residual PTSD from Java. Updated.